# Outlook (Office365) mail box layout looks messed up: Names & subjects not fully visible

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

This is hard to describe accurately by words so I'll use figures instead. Normally, Outlook email list looks like the picture on the left ([source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2014/09/03/propose-new-time-new-feature-outlook-web-app-office-365/)). Now, my email inbox looks very messy (picture on the right). Something is clearly wrong with the layout, and I have no clue how to fix it.

[image]

#### What I have tried?

- Online Repair (appwiz.cpl -> Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus -> Right Click -> Change -> Online repair)
- Reinstall (appwiz.cpl -> Remove Microsoft Office 365 -> Restart computer -> Reinstall by running `OfficeSetup.exe` with admin rights, downloaded from office.com)

The problem *might* have started because of an Online repair, which repaired a non-working search functionality. The Outlook version is Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12527.21296) 64-bit. Version 2002 (Build 12527.21330 Click-to-Run), on Windows 10.

What should I do to get the view from the current (right) back to normal (left)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it solved but will leave this here, if someone else faces the same problem. I had to select "View -> Change View -> **Send To**" or **Compact**. I think I tried all the possible view settings but somehow missed it.

Also Clicking the **Reset View** (on View tab, when visible) button has provided a quick fix.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. By the way, would you mind accepting your own reply as the answer so that others who might have a similar question can benefit from your thread?

Comment: Yeah I can do that. Just have to wait the required two days to pass for accepting own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After running after my own tail for a couple of days, I discover a solution very similar to the accepted one but slightly different. Actually, I clicked on the compact view, and then I reset the view. That worked very well.

Comment: This was exactly what I had too